# How to supprt 'Asynchronous Request-Response with CallBack' using spring-ws?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws, asynccallback

I am using 'Spring-WS' to develop web service, but I don't know how to support the 'Asynchronous Request-Response with 'CallBack' feature.
I want to get the following flow:
1.Client submit request(replyTo) -> Server returns 202 Accepted
2.Server submit callback request -> Client returns 200 OK
When I add the WS-Addressing feature, it only supports synchronized invocation.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: I would say that Spring's `WS-Addressing`-support does not contain what the average developer would expect to find, e.g. an api for providing the asynchronous reponse back to the ReplyTo url.